# Add multiple text files in Solr using SolrJ api

Tags: java, apache, solr, solrj

I am trying to find a way of how to upload multiple raw text files in SOlr using SolrJ api i Java. Below is my code:

Java Code:

```
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();

ContentStreamUpdateRequest solrRequest = new 
ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");

solrRequest.addFile(new File(fileName), "application/pdf");

solrRequest.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);

client.request(solrRequest);
```

This works for a single file. What if I need to upload multiple files. I can see there is one Post jar present in Solr-version/bin folder for that purpose. Is there the same thing available in SolrJ. Please help.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Munish

Comment: Hey did you find the solution?

Comment: That was an R and D work but unfortunately could not get the answer from anywhere. Meanwhile started working on something else so could not proceed further on this. I guess you need to use post jar to to upload multiple files or write logic from code to feed multiple files to Solr one by one.

Comment: do you know how to start solr server using java program rather than from command line?

Comment: String urlString = "http://host:port/solr/core_name/";
SolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(urlString).build();
ContentStreamUpdateRequest solrRequest = new  ContentStreamUpdateRequest("/update/extract");
solrRequest.addFile(new File(fileName), "application/pdf");
solrRequest.setParam("literal.id", id);
solrRequest.setParam("literal.place", fileName);
solrRequest.setAction(AbstractUpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, true, true);
SolrDocument doc = new SolrDocument();
NamedList<Object> result  = client.request(solrRequest);

Using SolrJ api in Java.